# Склеить аудио с помощью ffmpeg

Tags: linux, debian, аудио, ffmpeg

Представим, что у меня есть 3 файла с музыкой.

```
1.mp3
2.mp3
3.mp3
```

Длятся они по 2 минуты, допустим. Как мне объединить эти три файла так, чтобы был "плавный переход". Так, чтобы на 1:55 начал играть новый трек, а старый заканчивался, но не отключался? Соответственно, на 3:50 начинает играть третий трек, а второй доигрывает концовку

Comment: https://www.audacityteam.org/

Comment: Необходимо именно через ffmpeg. Ибо будет использоваться через самописную программу

Comment: Попробуйте этот ответ https://superuser.com/a/1363473

Comment: @Vadik Попробовал. `ffmpeg -i ./music/1.mp3 -i ./music/2.mp3 -i ./music/3.mp3 -vn -filter_complex "[0][1]acrossfade=d=10:c1=tri:c2=tri[a01]; [a01][2]acrossfade=d=10:c1=tri:c2=tri[a02]; [a02][3]acrossfade=d=10:c1=tri:c2=tri" out.mp3`. Выдаёт ошибку `Invalid file index 3 in filtergraph description [0][1]acrossfade=d=10:c1=tri:c2=tri[a01]; [a01][2]acrossfade=d=10:c1=tri:c2=tri[a02]; [a02][3]acrossfade=d=10:c1=tri:c2=tri.` К каждому файлу

Comment: @Vadik Нашёл решение проблемы тут https://superuser.com/questions/1648620/invalid-file-index-3-in-filtergraph-description-ffmpeg Теперь надо разобраться почему он из 3 трехминутных дорожен склеил на 11:30 файл

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1326240/%d0%9f%d0%be%d0%bc%d0%be%d0%b3%d0%b8%d1%82%d0%b5-%d0%bd%d0%b0%d0%b9%d1%82%d0%b8-%d0%be%d1%88%d0%b8%d0%b1%d0%ba%d1%83-%d0%b2-%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%bc%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%b4%d0%b5-ffmpeg?noredirect=1#comment2343611_1326240
Решение вопроса