# Помогите найти ошибку в команде ffmpeg

Tags: ffmpeg

Имеется команда:

```
ffmpeg -i ./music/1.mp3 -i ./music/2.mp3 -i ./music/3.mp3 -vn 
-filter_complex
"[0][0]acrossfade=d=10:o=1:c1=tri:c2=tri[00];
[00][1]acrossfade=d=10:o=1:c1=tri:c2=tri[01];
[01][2]acrossfade=d=10:o=1:c1=tri:c2=tri"
out.mp3
```

И она даже работает! Только вот почему-то когда файлы склеиваются в один, то 1.mp3 дважды подряд проигрывается в начале трека. Помогите разобраться где закралась ошибка.

Comment: `[0][0]` ← ну вот тут видимо вы склеиваете первый файл с первым файлом

Comment: @andreymal Оставил только [0]. Теперь 2.mp3 проигрывается дважды подряд

Comment: Фильтр acrossfade требует на своём входе два аудио. Если вы оставили только одно аудио, то, видимо, второе аудио взялось откуда-то автоматически, и в итоге получается, что вот тут `[00][1]` вы склеиваете первый-второй файл со вторым файлом

Comment: @andreymal большое спасибо! Сделал вот так `ffmpeg -i ./music/1.mp3 -i ./music/2.mp3 -i ./music/3.mp3 -vn -filter_complex "[0][1]acrossfade=d=10:o=1:c1=tri:c2=tri[a00]; [a00][2]acrossfade=d=10:o=1:c1=tri:c2=tri" out.mp3`. Все прекрасно работает)

Comment: Напишите ответ в [предыдущем вопросе](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1326180)?

Comment: @andreymal безусловно